# Custom Marker Icon not showing Google Static Maps v2

Tags: google-maps, httprequest, google-maps-static-api

I am using the Static Google Maps API v2 to download a static image of a map view with a singular marker just showing one image. However, the image added to the `marker` parameter of the url doesn't seem to be making any difference, and just a red marker is shown at the location.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=37.446754,-77.572746
&size=70x61
&maptype=roadmap
&sensor=true
&scale=2
&zoom=15
&key=some_key
&markers=icon:https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/financial_bg_64.png|37.446754,-77.572746
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

your image URL must remove the letter S HTTPS secure site, so work, for example like this:

```
http://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/financial_bg_64.png
```

complete code:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=37.446754,-77.572746&size=70x61&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false
&scale=2&zoom=15
&markers=icon:http://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/financial_bg_64.png|37.446754,-77.572746
```

Comment: Are you saying that HTTPS is not support for icons?

Answer (score 10):

In my experience,
There is no such requirement of http or https just care for icon size .
icon size should not exceed more than 64X64 pixels in size , Static map will happily show the custom icon . accept if found correct @max_

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center=37.446754,-77.572746&size=70x61&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false
&scale=2&zoom=15
&markers=icon:http://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/financial_64X64.png|37.446754,-77.572746
```

off course use your image with below 64X64 dimension instead of

```
http://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/shops/financial_64X64.png
```

Comment: Thank you.  64x64.  Wow.  Not mentioned on this page at all: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if it were about the V3 API (question is about V2), at least for typical icons. Both http and https work in V3. The documentation vaguely suggest that the maximum size is 4048 (I assumed it would scale down for me), but it worked only when I reduced the image size to 64x64. From the API doc: `Icons may be up to 4096 pixels maximum size (64x64 for square images)`

Answer (score 2):

You're actually not doing anything wrong, it's Google to blame:

"The Google Static Maps API does not support custom icon URLs that use HTTPS"